# Conditional comments syntax

Tags: html, if-statement, comments, conditional-statements

Can anyone explain me the difference between first and second conditional comment syntax?

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Why the second one use use the `<!-->` syntax before `<html>` tag? Can I use the following syntax with the same result?

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><html class="no-js"><![endif]-->
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The better question would be why that horrid old code is in the app / site in the first place. Conditional comments have gone the way of the dodo quite some time ago. (BTW, the second line allows any browser greater than IE8, or any other browser, to use that class.

Comment: So how can i menage user with older browser for a full compatibilty?

Comment: First, if the user is using IE8 or older, tell the user to get a new browser, update his computer, or similar. Such old software is a security risk. That being said, if the site is coded properly, there shouldn't be a need for conditional IE-comments. Proper HTML, and CSS designed to be backwards compatible, should take care of almost anything you can throw at it. And in the rare cases where defaults just can't hack it, you can throw in specific CSS-hacks just for IE.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie And for the latter in your comment, that is exactly what a _conditional comment is for_, to adjust know browsers issues. To have to add specific hacks inside the original CSS will just add more work to a future clean up, conditional does not.

Comment: Eh...? It does the exact same thing, except that when you do it all in CSS, you don't have to clean up the HTML, you can just remove the "hack" from the CSS-file. For the above one, you will have to remove the HTML/conditional AND The class it adds to the CSS (which probably is quite a bit of CSS, since all it does is add a parent class to wrap around other tags). Even worse, if the conditional comment is made to insert a separate stylesheet, which was also common several years ago. Personally, I haven't needed a single conditional the last... 5-6 years at least.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Of course it does the same, didn't say it didn't, and I haven't used it either, ever, in +20 years, still, the conditional comment will make the main CSS clean, so no clean up of it is necessary, assumed all hacks will be in the conditional CSS, which they should ... so one only need to remove the conditional comment and that's it

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Another benefit, all the hacks will only load when needed and not pollute the main CSS ... which will make the main CSS load faster for the majority of users

Comment: You need to read that conditional again. All it does is add a class to prefix IE specific CSS with. There is no IE specific stylesheet. And multiple CSS files for the same media-target is still a hassle and shouldn't be done. And it's pretty good to not have used them for 20+ years... CSS is 19 years old, and the conditionals showed up quite a bit after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your second setup will not be the same as your first.

In the first, where `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->` is used, it will let all other browsers (the one's that does not understand conditional comments) to have `<html class="no-js">`, which the second setup won't

Src: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

General accepted syntax is *(was)*

```
open tag   : <!--[if condition version]>
end tag    : <![endif]-->
```

Best guess is that its an *attempt* at a [bogus comment](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#bogus-comment-state). Two dashes after `<!` make it a comment node in the DOM. Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068759/7152454)

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
                 ^^^^^                    ^^^^       
                 |||||                    ||||
                 ________Bogus Comment________
```

It doesn't really make any difference. The last one will probably render as a `<!-- comment -->` or a `comment + condition` ... not sure.